# difference between ClassicComponentClass and ComponentClass in reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, interface, typescript, definition

I create my typescript definitions for some `reactJS` components and I see that in react.d.ts file there is 2 interfaces:

```
interface ComponentClass<P> {
    new(props?: P, context?: any): Component<P, ComponentState>;
    propTypes?: ValidationMap<P>;
    contextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    childContextTypes?: ValidationMap<any>;
    defaultProps?: P;
    displayName?: string;
}
```

and:

```
interface ClassicComponentClass<P> extends ComponentClass<P> {
    new(props?: P, context?: any): ClassicComponent<P, ComponentState>;
    getDefaultProps?(): P;
}
```

I see that ClassicComponentClass extends ComponentClass, but when I should use one of these? (when creating definition for component) Does this depends on how the component was created?

Comment: Why do you need either one? Why not using `Component`? These two are interfaces of the Component classes not instances. In most cases you create a component of your own by extending `Component`

Comment: but I don't create my own component. I only create definition for it. For example:
declare module "react-whatever" { 
   interface reactWhaterverProps{
      id:number;
      name:string;
   }\n
   let reactWhaterver: __React.ComponentClass<reactWhateverProps>\n
   export default reactWhaterver;
}
so I don't need create some 'state' interface in this case, because it's not mine component and it's state is black box for me, is it correct?

Comment: Why not `React.Component<ReachWhateverProps>`? What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: It's just not possible by typescript error because "Component" has 2 params <P,S>. I need only <P>. I create some definitions for react in DefinitelyTyped project. Here is one my example: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/react-calendar-timeline/react-calendar-timeline.d.ts

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are missing what `ComponentClass` is.

Here's a short example:

```
interface MyClassClass {
    new (): MyClass;
}

class MyClass {}

let ctor: MyClassClass = MyClass;
let instance: MyClass = new ctor();
```

In this example `MyClass` is like `React.Component` and `MyClassClass` is `React.ComponentClass`.

The actual instances in your case are the components and not the component class, and you should use that.
If you don't want to specify a state then you can simply do:

```
React.Component<ReachWhateverProps, {}>
```

---

#### Edit

First, in the future if your comment includes code (that spans across a few lines) then just edit your question and add the code and asking the follow up questions, and just add a comment saying that you've edited your question, that will make it much easier to understand the code.

As for the difference between the class vs instance, I think that the best example is the javascript `Array`.
If you look at the definition (in `lib.d.ts`) you'll see (depending on whether it's ES5 or ES6):

```
interface Array<T> {
    // array instance methods
}

interface ArrayConstructor {
    new (arrayLength?: number): any[];
    new <T>(arrayLength: number): T[];
    new <T>(...items: T[]): T[];
    (arrayLength?: number): any[];
    <T>(arrayLength: number): T[];
    <T>(...items: T[]): T[];
    isArray(arg: any): arg is Array<any>;
    prototype: Array<any>;
}

declare var Array: ArrayConstructor;
```

(from the ES5 `lib.d.ts`)

As you can see all of the instance member/methods (such as `length`, `push` etc) are in the `Array<T>` interface, the ctor functions and static class functions (such as `Array.isArray`) are in the `ArrayConstructor` definition.

In javascript class ctors are just functions that are called using the `new` keyword, so this:

```
class A {
    x: number;

    constructor(x: number) {
        this.x = x;
    }
}
```

compiles into:

```
var A = (function () {
    function A(x) {
        this.x = x;
    }
    return A;
}());
```

So `A` is basically just a function, and in order to create an instance you simply:

```
let a: A = new A(5);
```

So the ctor interface is: `{ new (x: number): A }`, or:

```
interface AConstructor {
    new (x: number): A;
}
```

As for react, it is recommended to have instance data in the `props` or `state` and not as class members.
The reason for this is that the `Component` lifecycle is only aware of those and react to changes in them.
So I'd do something like:

```
interface MyComponentProperties {
    id: string; 
    name: string;
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<MyComponentProperties, {}> {
    render() {
        return <div className={ this.props.id }>{ this.props.name }</div>;
    }
}

let myComponent = <MyComponent id="mc4" name="my component 4" />
```

Comment: I think I got it, so if I want create definition for component I should think about component as about function that takes interface as constructor for react component and return new instance of it? So result will be: declare module "some-react-component" {
    interface SomeReactComponent {
  id:number;
  name:any;
    }
    
    let SomeReactComponent:new() => React.Component<SomeReactComponent,{}>
    export default SomeReactComponent;
}
is it correct?

Comment: Check my revised answer, hopefully it will make things clearer